# Registration Form: function prepare() on null

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a registration form (using an SQL database) that utilizes my 
"register.inc.php" file, When I attempt to create an account (as a test) I get

**THIS error:** 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /usr/www/world/includes/register.inc.php on line 30"

I've posted the code from my register.inc.php, any insight would be much appreciated.

```
    <?php
include_once 'loginhandler.php';
include_once 'DBclass.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
            $stmt->close();
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this username already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists</p>';
            $stmt->close();
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {

        // Create hashed password using the password_hash function.
        // This function salts it with a random salt and can be verified with
        // the password_verify function.
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It means that your mysqli-object (`$mysqli`) is `null`. Something has gone wrong when you tried to assign it.

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for the quick response. I don't see anything that would cause that.. I thought it might be something to do with my database table not existing, but it is in fact working as intended.. When I manually create a user in my database and then login with my form it works flawlessly, its the matter of registering a new user that has me stumped.

Comment: DragonKyn Try `var_dump($mysqli)` just to see what it shows. I'm suspecting that it fails to connect to your database for whatever reason when creating the connection object.

Comment: That's a great place to start, I'll give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Oh, try `$mysqli->connect_error`! The `var_dump` may be redundant, but `connection_error` may help you!

Comment: Hey Max, you were right. It dumps as null. I'm so confused - I'm preparing it: $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";

Comment: DragonKyn You need to establish a connection with the server somewhere. As Jorge Fernando Matricali says in his answer, you haven't assigned `$mysqli` to anything in your current code. Unless you haven't done it yet, you need to assign `$mysqli` before using it as such:  `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Comment: That was exactly the problem, I forgot to open the connection. Oh my gosh. Thanks guys I feel like a complete moron.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that 'DBclass.php' contains an assignment to "$ mysqli" variable. It's correct? Because in your current script it does not contain any assigment to this variable. (So it's OK, it contains null value because it's never initialized)